# iAd strange console "Unhandled error"

Tags: iphone, xcode, iad

I'm seeing in the console:

> "Unhandled error (no delegate or
>   delegate does not implement
>   didFailToReceiveAdWithError:):"

Although didFailToReceiveAdWithError is being invoked (I can see that with check points and in the console log)

Does someone has any reasonable explanation? It's like it's working and not working all in the same time. I'm not using IB for the adview, and have added it programmatically and have set the adview.delegate = self. I'm also using three20 in this project if that changes anything.

It's like sometimes he knows who's his delegate and sometime not...

Comment: Anyone?! I can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

The Apple documentation says:

> While you are developing your application, iAd Network sends test advertisements to your application. To assist you in validating your implementation, the iAd Network occasionally returns errors to test your error handling code.

In my app iAd also returns a mix of correct banners, error 3, error 5, ... and so on. Maybe this problem will disappear after the release of the app when iAd changes from

> iAd Network serves test ads

to

> iAd Network serves live ads if you signed the iAd Network Agreement and enabled advertising for your application